# How to keep JSON updated on my backend

Tags: java, json, angularjs, architecture

I have an architectural doubt.
The backend of my system is a Spring MVC application with MongoDB. I receive and return JSON objects to my frontend, which is written in HTML + AngularJS. Nothing on my frontend is processed using Java.

So, imagine a table, like a Excel table. It will be like a list of lists on my JSON. I send this JSON to my frontend that will show to the user.

```
[  
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
]
```

Now let's say that the user changes 5 to 0. In my frontend this will be the current object:

```
[  
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 0, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
]
```

How do you would change this on the backend? Everytime the user changes something, I check it and send the new value with the line and column number? Ask the user to click save, and then send the entire JSON again? How the things are be done today in this type of environment?

Thank you!

Comment: that isn't a JSON notation,is just an array

Comment: what are you using for your middleware? you can use sockets for duplex realtime communication

Comment: The example was not the best one, I admit. But since my frontend can be a mobile app using HTML + JS, I can't use socket, can I?

Comment: How exactly do you communicate with the backend now? "Spring MVC" is kind of broad. Is it done through RESTful webservices? Or manual ajaxed HTTP posts?

Comment: @rcorreia yes you can, it doesn't matter if you are targetting mobile apps in the end is HTML/js combination you can find a lot of socket libraries that works with javascript in the client-side

Comment: @Gimby So, I really don't know yet that difference. I use annotations to create my services on Spring MVC controller. Like @ApiMethod(path = "/user/add", verb = ApiVerb.POST, description = "Inserts an user on the database", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example an array is used and not a JSON object.

You are just changing the index of the array not its value.

you shouldn't be using an array here at all you should use a regular object. All Javascript objects function as associative arrays.

```
String json = '"data":[
    {"key":"1", "key":"2","key":"3"}, 
    {"key":"4", "key":"5", "key":"6"}, 
    {"key":"7", "key":"8", "key":"9"}
]';
```

To convert it to DBObject, you can code like this :

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
```

And save it in the database.

*I hope my answer helps you.*